# Bulk Insert in SSMS not working on Windows 7

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, csv, insert

I tried to do the following in Windows 7 in SQL Server Management Studio for SQL Server 2008, and I get the error below.

```
BULK INSERT subprocess 
    FROM 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\subprocess.csv' 
    WITH 
    ( 
        FIRSTROW = 1, -- if column headers then this should be set to 2
        MAXERRORS = 0, 
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' 
    )
```

Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot bulk load because the file "C:\Users\me\Desktop\subprocess.csv" could not be opened. Operating system error code 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).

Comment: What's unclear about the error?

Comment: I'm guessing I have to put my CSV on the server where SQL Server is, right?  I have it on my desktop where I'm connecting.  I don't have access to that server file system.  Is there a way to change the command to grab the file from my local machine where I'm running SSMS?  As a workaround, I just followed this article, and pasted my data.  http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2008/02/25/simple-copypaste-to-load-data-from-excel-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path referenced in the FROM clause is relative to where the BULK INSERT clause is running, so the path you've given should be on the C: drive of the SQL Server machine. The user account the command is running under needs to have adequate file system permissions to the file, also.

No, you don't have to have the files located on your SQL Server, but whatever path you use a) has to be valid to the SQL Server at execution time and b) proper permissions need to be granted.  We use UNC-style paths (\\machine\path...) in our system and our users decide where to put things.